# Trying to download Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to install Magento 1 on my WAMP localhost server. The only file available for download from magento.com is the `downloader.php` file. I have absolutely no idea what settings to use in order to get this downloader to connect and download the magento files....

Is there a direct download anywhere - or instructions as to how to use the infernal downloader? (the installation guide seems to have been removed from magento.com  too... the link goes to 404 page)

Why make things simple? - I'm seriously considering a move away from Magento...

Answer (score 3):

You can download Magento files from the official website: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

Just scroll down to the 1.x version.

Comment: It seems Magento 1.x is no longer available there?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to download Magento version 1.9.x.

**Method 1:** Go to https://magento.com/tech-resources/download. Press **`CTRL + F`** and search for **`1.9.3.`**. Here you will get the link to download the latest version of Magento 1.9.3.x.

**Method 2:** Apart from above, there are two teams who are managing the updated Magento 1.x releases.

Below are the links for downloading the latest Magento 1.9.3.8.

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/archive/1.9.3.8.zip

https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/archive/1.9.3.8.zip

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can Download All The Version Since First to Latest:- 
**https://blog.magestore.com/magento-download/**